# socket.emit doing nothing, but socket.on seems to have worked

Tags: reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, open to any help.

I need to use a socket event but for some reason I cannot get socket.emit/socket.on to work. Using React and Typescript.

I'm using the following:

(the stateful `socket` variable is set after .on('connect', ...) event )

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (socket) { 
    socket.on('testing123', (data: string) => console.log("test data", data))
  }
}, [socket]);
```

And on a button on the page:

```
<button
  onClick={() => {
    console.log('button click');
    socket?.emit('testing123', {foo: "bar"});
  }}
>
</button>
```

That's about it. When I click the button, I don't see the console.log('test data', data).
The socket is connected. I can `console.log(socket)` before the .emit and before the .on, it shows about the same object, same ids, etc.

If I log socket right before the .emit, I see the object includes _callbacks, which are listed as '$connect' and '$testing123'. It appears to include the correct functions (as in (data: string) => console.log("test data", data))). `socket.onAnyOutgoing((eventName, ..args) => console.log(eventName))` does print the event 'testing123' when I click the button.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I'm losing my mind a bit, have no idea why this isn't working.

Open to any direct help or advice on how to debug this.

Comment: `socket.on('testing123', ...)` will fire when the server emits the event `testing123`, not when a client emits `testing123`. At the moment  `socket?.emit('testing123', {foo: "bar"});` emits to the server, where you then need to handle that message and then broadcast a message back to the other clients (that is if your goal is for everyone to receive that emitted message). Normally the message you broadcast from the server to the clients would have a different name though.

Comment: @NickParsons [not really](https://socket.io/docs/v4/broadcasting-events/#to-all-connected-clients).

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon What am I missing? That link is talks about sending the message from the server, which is what I said right?: _"where you then need to handle that message and then broadcast a message back to the other clients"_

Comment: No @NickParsons this is talking about emitting to all connected clients including the active client that sent the message.

Comment: Share the code which you used to initialize the `socket`

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon Yeah, but emitting to all connected clients from the server. My point is that OP has just shown client code, they're not emitting from the server, they're trying to emit to other clients from the client (seemingly without having the server involved).

Comment: Yes emitting to all connected clients from the server. the OP needs to include server code and even more of client code.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon Yes, I think we're both trying to say the same thing then. That is what I said originally as well  _"where you then need to handle that message and then broadcast a message back to the other clients "_